# Tumblr: Show Post Number

Tags: css, tumblr

I'm tinkering with Tumblr themes for the first time and I was wondering if there was a way to display the number of a post. With the first post being #1 and the second post being #2, so on and so forth?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there isn't a theme operator that will print out the current post number, as Tumblr doesn't support this kind of logic / feature.

However, you can fake it:

**CSS**

```
.post:nth-child( 1 ) .number:after {
  content: ' 1';
}
.post:nth-child( 2 ) .number:after {
  content: ' 2';
}
.post:nth-child( 3 ) .number:after {
  content: ' 3';
}
.post:nth-child( 4 ) .number:after {
  content: ' 4';
}
.post:nth-child( 5 ) .number:after {
  content: ' 5';
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="post">
    <p class="number">Post</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <p class="number">Post</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <p class="number">Post</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <p class="number">Post</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <p class="number">Post</p>
  </div>
```

**Result** http://jsbin.com/kahisiqipe